# R Studio, ctrl + shift + c not commenting

Tags: r, rstudio

In R Studio, I want to comment lines so I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, however it doesn't give me the # sign but

like:

```
Import packages
```

and it becomes:

```
<!-- Import packages -->
```

what's the right setting/keyboard shortcut?

thank you

Comment: Are you editing a R Markdown file? In that case, `<!-- text  -->` is how you comment .

Comment: @headpoint, yes, it's a .rmd file. thank you, I thought it's always #..

Comment: Yes, that's how you'd comment a R markdown file. Nothing to worry there.

Comment: @headpoint, would you consider to post it as an anwswer? it's good knowledge. (it would be perfect if you can tell how to save .rmd to .R file too)

Comment: I meant, how can I save the .Rmd File to a R File?

Comment: Other than extracting R code chunks (manually or using an external tool), I am not aware of facility to export Rmd files to R in Rstudio. I also do not see much use in doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  R Markdown, following is used for commenting out text.

```
<!-- lines to comment goes here -->
```

(Normal R style comments (#) need to be used within R code chunks)